# BBEdit chomp off excessive decimals

Tags: regex, bbedit

Having a very large data set of float values where the precision is not longer needed, what is a regular expression that I can use with BBEdit to allow me to keep a maximum of 5 digits after a period?

Physically, the decimal value always has a character preceeding the period, is always preceeded by a space, but can have a comma or a space **after** the string.

sample:

```
 -162.40904700399989, -82.896416924999954
```

Comment: It seems you only need to search for `(\.{5})\d+` and replace it with first capturing group value `\1` or `$1`.

Comment: That expression yields no hits.   I can find them with `(\d+\.\d{5})\d*` but replacing is where failure strikes...

Comment: oops!  `\1` does work on the replacement.  Guess I had a typo and my eyes crossed...

Comment: Sorry, I missed a `\d`. It should be `(\.\d{5})\d+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

**Find**:       `(\d\.\d{5})\d+`
**Replace**: `\1`

**Details**

- `(\d\.\d{5})` - Group 1 (referred to via `\1` from the replacement pattern): a digit, `.` and then 5 digits (note the first `\d` has no quantifier, we are not interested if there are more than one, one is enough, before the decimal separator)
- `\d+` - ***one*** or more digits. Note the `+` quantifier makes more sense than `*` because we only want to match those numbers that we want to modify, those that already have 5 digits after the decimal separator do not have to be matched.